# Drooping Aloe? Is my Aloe healthy?

Tags: plant-health, soil, aloe

A friend just gave me this aloe. It has grown a lot since she had it and has two pups now. however, I'm noticing aloe online looks like it grows up whereas the large leaves at the base of my aloe are growing out.

Is my aloe healthy?!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That glass jar doesn't have any drainage holes in it. Put it in a proper plant pot, and don't over-water it. The depth of soil in the jar is very small for the size of the plant as well.

Probably the other leaves would "flop" if the jar wasn't supporting them. This looks like a small specimen of a big species of Aloe - some species grow to the size of trees, and are great outdoor plants in the right climate, but not suitable for growing indoors in pots.